# Как запустить задачи gulp watch сразу

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

Есть следующий gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    merge = require('merge-stream'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug')
    path = require('path'),
    rootDir = 'design/default',
    paths = {
        sass: rootDir + '/sass',
        css: rootDir + '/css',
        images: ['brands', 'uploads']
    },
    browsers = ['> 5%', 'Firefox > 10', 'ie >= 8', 'Chrome > 15', 'Safari > 3'],
    isDevelopment = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return sass(paths.sass + '/style.scss', {
        style: 'expanded',
        loadPath: [paths.sass]
    })
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: browsers
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css));
});

gulp.task('images', function(cb) {
    var tasks = paths.images.map(function (subDir) {
        return gulp.src(['files/' + subDir + '/*.jpg', 'files/' + subDir + '/*.png'])
            .pipe(newer('files/' + subDir + '/test'))
            .pipe(imagemin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('files/' + subDir + '/test'));
    });

    return merge(tasks);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.sass + '/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
    gulp.watch(['files/**/*', '!files/**/test'], gulp.series('images'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'));
```

Когда в терминале пишу **gulp**, запускается **task deafult** и начинается **watch**. Но сами задачи запустятся только при изменении какого-либо файла. Как сделать чтобы при запуске команды **gulp** задачи в **watch** выполнились сразу, а потом уже было наблюдение за изменениями?

Comment: gulp.task('watch', `['styles', 'images'],` function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.sass + '/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
    gulp.watch(['files/**/*', '!files/**/test'], gulp.series('images'));
});

Comment: У меня gulp 4 и там только 2 аргумента передается в task, массив передать нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('styles', 'images', 'watch'));
```

При вызове функции `gulp.series` "задания" gulp должны уже быть зарегистрированы. Функция `gulp.series` принимает задания/названия заданий и возвращает функцию, которая из них состоит. Каждое из заданий исполняется по очереди, в случае ошибки в каком-либо задании - исполнение цепочки обрывается. Этого можно избежать использовав `gulp.parallel`, при условии что задания не имеют зависимостей между собой.

Comment: @Сергей Мирошник, отметьте ответ как правильный, если он решает вашу проблему